# Can a positively charged insulator take electrons from a conductor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

If a positively charged insulator like glass came in contact with a conductor, would it just polarize the conductor or would it take some of the electrons from the conductor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very dependent on material, temperature, and purity. Current will leak, but it might take a century to cancel most of the positive charge. Or it might take a millisecond.

Comment: What if the materials were glass and aluminum at room temperature?

Comment: @Jeremiah Glass? There are many kinds. Some are very conductive. You'll need to find a glass with tabulated conductivity. Then, calculate the capacitance of the conductors and the resistance of the glass. The RC time constant then gives you your answer.